# SSRS - right align dynamic number of images

Tags: image, reporting-services

so i have an SSRS report that contains only one image control, that is getting image data from VARBINARY(MAX) column from the database.
[image]

I don't know how many images dataset query will fetch.
Currently, those images are shown one below another, losing precious whitespace to the right.
[image]

What i would like to do is to fit maximum possible number of images to the right, and go to the new line, when image size is higher than the remaining whitespace size on the right.

I've spent whole morning searching for this, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, solution is simple, create as many copies of image objects that you know will possibly fit horizontally. When you do that, for each image object, in Visibility pane, use this expression:

```
=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4) = 1, False, True)
```

where Mod 4 is number of image objects you have created. In every other image object, you are always adding one remainder to Mod 4 (so in another image object, you have Mod 4) = 2, Mod 4 = 3, etc. However, in the last image object, you use:

```
=IIF((RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4) = 0, False, True)
```